# SIGFPE Error in C?

Tags: c

I have the following code which calculates the number of trailing zeroes in factorial of a number. The program runs for the first testcase which is 10 but when the same code is run for 17 it shows a SIGFPE error in C?
Can anyone tell where i am going wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){
    int n,i=1,j,sum=0,l;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while((n/(5^i))>1)
    {
        j=(n/(5^i));
        i++;
        sum=sum+j;
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step through the program with your debugger and analyse your values to find where you're going wrong. Also, don't tag the wrong language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong is that you are using the operator `^` the wrong way: it is not the power operator, but the bitwise `XOR` operator. There is no power operator in C, but a pow() function the math library.

On the other way... where the factorial is calculated?

Comment: thanks! worked like a charm. What a foolish mistake thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: There is no need to calculate the factorial! The trailing zeroes could be calculated with the help of the number only.